# Set symbol's number on jQuery css statement

Tags: jquery, css, html

For example : I have a lot of select elements with names :

```
select name="XXXX"
select name="XXXXX"
select name="XXXXXX"
select name="XXXXXXX"
```

I would like to set some condition to select element that has it attribute name with 4 symbols (`name="XXXX"`).
I can do it in this way : `$('select[name="XXXX"] option')`
But I need something universal.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: How do you mean universal?

Comment: select's names attributes has been generating automatically.For 100% ,  I know that in my case I have some select element with name = 4 symbols (can be anything ex: 1234 or abcd).  
So I can't write $('select[name="1234"] option') . Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.filter` to define custom filtering conditions:

```js
console.log($('select').filter(function(i) {
  return $(this).attr('name').length == 4
}).find('option:selected').text())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="aaa"></select>
<select name="bbbb">
  <option selected="selected">b1</option>
  <option>b2</option>
</select>
<select name="ccccc"></select>
<select name="dddd">
  <option selected="selected">d1</option>
  <option>d2</option>
</select>
<select name="eee"></select>
```

Comment: And what about this case :
 $('select[name^="XXXX"] option').filter(':selected').text()

How I can use filter related to select attr ?

Comment: you can continue to use jQuery methods from the result. see updated answer